# Strange format from JodaTime when calculating time difference with Java

Tags: time, jodatime, localtime

I am trying to find the duration between two times with the below code:

```
                    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
                        System.out.println(airTime1);
                        System.out.println(startTime1);
                    Minutes difference = ((Minutes.minutesBetween(startTime1,airTime1)));
                    String differenceS = String.valueOf(difference);
                        System.out.println(differenceS);
                    LocalTime remaining1 = formatter.parseLocalTime(differenceS);
                        System.out.println(remaining1);
```

airTime1 & startTime1 are both localTime variables.  difference should contain the duration between the two times.  differenceS is a String representation of difference, as minutes cannot be converted to String.

When I enter times into the variables such as 12:00 & 13:00, the variables are recorded as: 12:00:00.000 & 13:00:00.000, but differenceS received a value of PT-60M, which obviously throws an error.  Does anyone know why the minutes difference line could be calculating this value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does *difference.getMinutes()* not work for you?

Comment: You mean using difference.getMinutes like this? Minutes difference1 = (difference.getMinutes(startTime1,airTime1));

Comment: No. The *Minutes* class of jodatime provides a method *getMinutes()* without any parameter that returns the amount of minutes represented as *int* value. Isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I want to do.  Sorry for my ignorance, how would I implement that?

Comment: Replace the last 4 lines in your code example by *System.out.println(difference.getMinutes())*. If you only need the absolute value (non-negative) use *Math.abs(int):int* for it.

Answer (score 1):

The **Minutes** class of *jodatime* overwrites the toString() method in a way that returns a String in ISO8601 duration format as mentioned in the [JavaDoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html#toString--). This is exactly what your *PT-60M* represents. A duration of -60 minutes.

If you just want the raw minutes printed your code could look like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
System.out.println(airTime1);
System.out.println(startTime1);
Minutes difference = Minutes.minutesBetween(startTime1,airTime1);
System.out.println(Math.abs(difference.getMinutes()));
```

Comment: Ah I see!  How would you convert the time from the ISO standard to a timestamp?

Comment: I don't understand your question. *Minutes* is a relative time value while *Timestamp* is a absolute value (a unique point in time). You cannot convert from *Minutes* to *Timestamp* without implying some context.

Comment: I think it must be my terminology.  So if it is outputting PT60M (positive value this time), how would you get it to just display 60?